# Changing the element of an array created from the props inside the child component also affect the parent component's props | Vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, spread

I have a parent component(App) in which I have an array of objects. I passed this array as a prop to the child component(UserLocations). Now inside the child component, I use this array and create a data variable.

So If I am going to change the one element of the array then why the parent component's property is also changed.

***App.Vue***

```
<template>
  <user-locations :initalLocations="locations"/>
</template>

<script>
import UserLocations from './components/UserLocations.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    UserLocations
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      locations: [
        {"id": 121, name: "test 121", "order": 1},
        {"id": 122, name: "test 122", "order": 2},
        {"id": 123, name: "test 123", "order": 3},
        {"id": 124, name: "test 124", "order": 4}
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

***UserLocations.vue***

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(location) in locations"
        :key="location.id"
        > 
        <span @click="decreaseOrder(location)">Up</span>
        {{ location.name}} {{location.order}}
        <span @click="increaseOrder(location)">down</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            locations: [...this.initalLocations]
        }
    },
    props: {
        initalLocations: { 
            type: Array,
        },
    },
    // computed: {
    //     locations() {
    //         return [
    //             ...this.initalLocations
    //         ]
    //     }
    // },
    methods:{
        increaseOrder(location) {
            if (location.order != this.locations.length) {
                this.locations = this.locations.map(l => {
                    var returnLocation = {...l};
                    if (l.id == location.id) {
                        l.order += 1
                    }
                    return returnLocation
                });
            }
        },
        decreaseOrder(location) {
            if (location.order != 1) {
                this.locations = this.locations.map(l => {
                    var returnLocation = {...l};
                    if (l.id == location.id) {
                        l.order -= 1
                    }
                    return returnLocation
                });
            }
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I use the `initalLocations` props to make the location prop inside UserLocations component and when I change one of the array's objects by click on either the up/down button, It changes the prop passed to the UserLocations instead of changing the local data "locations"

Comment: I was thinking the same because when I put the question, after 5-7 seconds someone downvote. Even this question needs 2-3 minutes to understand.

Comment: Try out  `locations: this.initalLocations.slice()` instead of `locations: [...this.initalLocations]`

Comment: Still updating the prop instead of local data 'locations;

Comment: I read something from here is that the mutation inside the child affects the parent, but I guess using spread we can get a new array ref. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow

Comment: the spread operator doesn't clone deeply the array

Comment: I think I should use `locations: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initalLocations))` statement to create local locations data variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator doesn't clone deeply the array, you need a function that clone the array instead of referencing it :

```
<script>
function deepCopy(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) {
        return obj;
    }


    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        return obj.reduce((arr, item, i) => {
            arr[i] = deepCopy(item);
            return arr;
        }, []);
    }

    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
            newObj[key] = deepCopy(obj[key]);
            return newObj;
        }, {})
    }
}

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            locations: deepCopy(this.initalLocations)
        }
    },
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. and yes I either use your function or `locations: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initalLocations))` (which may convert undefined to null) or lodash(third party)'s  deep clone function. Anyhow sometimes I forget the latest js function's functionality.